# creating data frame in R at runtime (Dynamically)

Tags: r, dynamic, for-loop, dataframe

I am doing analysis where a set of cross tabs have to be generated for a large set of distributors. The data is at a customer level and each customer is mapped to a distributor. Since the number of distributors are large, I am trying to automate the process.

I am getting stuck at dynamically creating data frames based on the distributor ID

**Here is what I am trying:**

```
for (i in 1:length(DiD)){ #vector comprising list of distributors
    paste("use",DiD[[1]],sep="_") <- subset(master table, Field1=="NA"& Field2=="valid" & Field3==as.character(DiD[[1]])) 
}
```

**Additional Info:**

```
DiD[[1]] = 1234
```

**Desired output:**
A data frame `use_1234` which contains the master data subset by `Field1`, `Field2` and by `DiD=1234`

**Errors Thrown:**
Facing issues with the paste part as well with specifying `Field3` as `DiD[[1]]`

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
dims [product 1] do not match the length of object [529]
```

I hope that I've provided sufficient information. Thanks a ton!

PS: Apologize if the questions has been answered in the forum, I could not find it.

Comment: You may want to look at `assign`. Also, it's good to avoid `subset` and instead use `[`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas , I will check assign. The other issue is to get the data frame name dynamically created. Any views on what might be going wrong there?

Comment: @agstudy has given you a good answer using `assign` that will probably solve your issue.

Comment: I will try @agstudy, I'll add some dummy tables to make the question more clear.Thanks for the suggestion. I will also add an answer once I have cracked this

Comment: @RaamaVi You should read [this to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could also solve this using `split`

```
dfs <- 
split(master.table[master.table$Field1=="NA" & # probably should be is.na(master.table$Field1), but we don't have the data
                   master.table$Field2=="valid",], Field3)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `for` here, subset will generate a data.frame:

```
 res <- subset(master.table,Field1== NA & 
                            Field2=="valid" & 
                            Field3==as.character(DiD[[1]]))
```

then you can use `assign` :

```
  assign(paste("use",DiD[[1]],sep="_"),res)
```

I guess , you need something like this , assuming that `DiD` is a list of names:

```
 list.df <- lapply(DiD, function(x)  subset(master.table,is.na(Field1) & 
                            Field2=="valid" & 
                            Field3==as.character(x)))
 names(list.df) <- DiD
```

This will create a named list of data.frames.

Comment: Thanks @agstudy . I'll try including the 2 code fragments within a for loop to take care of all data frames DiD[1:n]

Comment: @RaamaVi no need , used `lapply` is a loop, So DiD is a data.frame or a list? can you  add `str(DiD)`